# Reducing Equation Loop

Tags: python-3.7

I'm trying to create a loop where if the value of "X" is a whole number it divides it by 2 and that's the new value. Then if the new value is a whole number it divides by 2 or if it has a decimal it subtracts it by 0.5 and that becomes the new value. I want it to loop from "X" to >= 1.5

I've tried a while/if/elif and I get close but when I change my "X" value from 217 to 218 the output isn't right.

```
def func():
    val = 217
    while val >= 1.5:
        val = val/2
        print(val)
        if val is float:
            val = val-.5
            print(val)
        elif val is int:
            val = val/2
            print(val)
        else:
            val = val//2
            print(val)
func()
```

When val = 217 this renders perfectly with the exception of it going to 0.0 instead of 1.5

Also the else: val = val//2 seems off to me but this is the closest I've gotten to rending this code the way I want it to.

Output:

108.5
54.0
27.0
13.0
6.5
3.0
1.5
0.0  <--- don't get why this is here when the while loop states >= 1.5

Now if you change the val to 218

```
def func():
    val = 218
    while val >= 1.5:
        val = val/2
        print(val)
        if val is float:
            val = val-.5
            print(val)
        elif val is int:
            val = val/2
            print(val)
        else:
            val = val//2
            print(val)
func()
```

Output:

109.0
54.0
27.0
13.0
6.5
3.0
1.5
0.0

Kind of bugs out because 218/2 = 109 then 109/2 = 54.5

Since I want the code to print out each new value I would want it to show each value as if you're typing each equation then hitting the equals sign. I want the output to look like this:

Output:

109.0 (/2)
54.5 (-0.5)
54.0 (/2)
27.0 (/2)
13.5 (-0.5)
13.0 (/2)
6.5 (-0.5)
6.0 (/2)
3.0 (-1.5)
1.5 (>= 1.5)

Output is coming out close to what I want but not exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest test for whether the result of dividing value `x` by 2 is an integer is:

```
int(x / 2) == x / 2
```

or, in general:

```
int(expression) == expression # to test any expression for an integer value
# but typically the expression is just a variable to avoid redundant calculations
```

Try this:

```
def func():
    val = 218
    print(val, end='')
    while val >= 1.5:
        val /= 2
        print(' (/2)', val, end='')
        if int(val) != val:
            val -= .5
            if val >= 1.5:
                print(' (-0.5)', val, end='')
    print(' (>= 1.5)')

func()
```

See demo at http://ideone.com/wCOxta

Prints:

```
218 (/2) 109.0 (/2) 54.5 (-0.5) 54.0 (/2) 27.0 (/2) 13.5 (-0.5) 13.0 (/2) 6.5 (-0.5) 6.0 (/2) 3.0 (/2) 1.5 (>= 1.5)
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the conditions 'val is float' and 'val is int' are always false, you need another way to check whether the decimal part of val is 0 or not.

A rough way to do it (but there is better with no doubt) is :

```py
if (val * 10) % 10 == 0:  # If the decimal part is 0
```

Moreover, according to the algorithm you describe at the beginning, the final else shouldn't exist.
Besides, at the beginning of the loop, you forgot to divide the value by 2 only if it is round.

You make two different operations in each loop, that's why the final result may be one step ahead of what you expect, you may want to change the loop to make one operation at each iteration or add a condition on the second operation.

Comment: Thank you. You helped me get closer.

Answer (score 0):

Something smooth:

```py
x = 1.0

if type(x) is float:
    print("float")
elif type(x) is int:
    print("int")

>>> float
```